# How do I get the email value using the query string method?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using two plugins for Popup, window plugin and newsletter plugin. when popup shows, it displays the `EMAIL` field and Subscribe button

If customer enter the email and subscribe, the form action will redirect to `Subscribe-page.php` and the email value is returned from the poupup window

here is the code for popup window form

```
<form onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)" action="http://www.example.com /subscription/" class="content-sxzw" method="post">
         <input class="newsletter-email" type="email" placeholder="Your email here" name="ne" size="30" required>
         <input type="submit" class="submit-sxzw" value="{{subscribe-button-text}}" />
</form>
```

**Demo**

How do I get the email to subscribe page using the query string method?

Comment: change form method to get method="get" and get $_GET['email']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is kind of basic jQuery stuff. You can get email by this code

```
var userEmail = $(".newsletter-email").val();
```